# One image in a table with many rows

Tags: html

I am trying to create a responsive [image: table] with bootstrap with many rows but a single image in it (see attached). I am stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: here is the table: https://ibb.co/bFd03MP

Comment: what good is an image?  where's the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the property you are looking for is rowspan

```css
td {
  width: 10vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

img {
  width: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td rowspan='3'><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/300"></td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was looking for.

Comment: I updated it to make it completely responsive